# How to set [name] of output.chunkFilename to be the same with [name] of output.filename?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

In webpack 2 I defined output like this:

```
  module.exports.output = {
    filename: `js/[name].js`,
    chunkFilename: `js/[id].[name].js`,
  }
```

When devServer starts, entry file is `main.js` as expected. However, the chunk file is requested as `0.0.js`, what should I do if I want `0.main.js`? Also I'm curious  why can't chunkFilename's [name] be in accord with filename's [name]?

Comment: The `[name]` placeholder for chunkFilename refers to the chunk's name (which is dynamic for every chunk) rather than your entry's name. Try `js/[id].main.js` instead.